# How to properly align text in an Excel cell using OpenPyXL so that it doesn't repeat or overflow

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm creating an Excel from scratch using openpyxl. Some of the cells are populated with long strings, if the string is too long, I want it to cut at the cell border and not overflow to the neighboring cell.

This can be achieved using `Alignment(horizontal='fill')`, but then if the string is too short it repeats the string to *fill* the cell.

How can I achieve both no-overflow and no-repeat?

Overflow without `Alignment(horizontal='fill')`:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
cell_style = NamedStyle(name='cell_style')
wb.add_named_style(cell_style)

ws = wb.active
ws['A1'].value = 'abcdefghijklmnop'
ws['A1'].style = 'cell_style'

wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

Output:

[image]

Repeat with `Alignment(horizontal='fill')`:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, Alignment

cell_style = NamedStyle(name='cell_style')
cell_style.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='fill')

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
wb.add_named_style(cell_style)
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'].value = 'abc'
ws['A1'].style = 'cell_style'
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This just happens because the neighboring cell is empty. This has nothing to do directly with Python. If you write anything in cell B1 the text will be cut like you want

Comment: Do you want "Alignment(wrap_text=True)"?  This 'should' wrap the text to the cell as required.  I've always found Excel's wrapping to be a little weird though...

Comment: @Thickycat this breaks it into multiple lines, possible but not ideal. The stragne part is the repeat, why does *fill* cause repeat?

Comment: My best answer there, I'm afraid, is "because that's what Excel does".  It's what it means by 'fill' - fill the cell using the text you've provided.  Probably makes more sense when the 'text' is something like "-" to give a horizontal line the width of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use wrap_text and fix the row height back to default. Alignment is set to vertical top so the start of the text is shown in the cell.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, Alignment

cell_style = NamedStyle(name='cell_style')
cell_style.alignment = Alignment(vertical='top', wrap_text=True)

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
wb.add_named_style(cell_style)
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'].value = 'abcdefghijklmnopq'
ws['A1'].style = 'cell_style'
ws['A2'].value = 'abc'
ws['A2'].style = 'cell_style'
for i in range(1,3):
    ws.row_dimensions[ws[f'A{i}'].row].height = ws.sheet_format.defaultRowHeight
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```